# Can not run the functions of Microsoft's API Magnification in C

Tags: c++, windows

I took from this page:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms692402%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#initializing_the_magnifier_run-time_library

This function example:

```
BOOL SetZoom(float magnificationFactor)
{
    // A magnification factor less than 1.0 is not valid.
    if (magnificationFactor < 1.0)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    // Calculate offsets such that the center of the magnified screen content 
    // is at the center of the screen. The offsets are relative to the 
    // unmagnified screen content.
    int xDlg = (int)((float)GetSystemMetrics(
            SM_CXSCREEN) * (1.0 - (1.0 / magnificationFactor)) / 2.0);
    int yDlg = (int)((float)GetSystemMetrics(
            SM_CYSCREEN) * (1.0 - (1.0 / magnificationFactor)) / 2.0);

    return MagSetFullscreenTransform(magnificationFactor, xDlg, yDlg);
}
```

And I just did - Copy - Paste into Dev-C++

But when I compile this code I get an error:

```
'BOOL' does not name a type
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: the error is:
'BOOL' does not name a type

Comment: Did you include `<windows.h>`?

Comment: I did it now.
Look what happened:
http://i.imgur.com/jbmMT.jpg

Comment: Please post all information here (i.e. copy and paste). Screen shots are not very helpful for us to help you.You can edit your question by clicking the link below it.

Comment: @user1687536, #include is something you use in your first C program, which you should really learn a fair bit of before starting this.

Comment: I might as well point out that this is Windows-8 specific, you need to include `Magnification.h`, and you need to link to `Magnification.lib`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the error message is telling you that the compiler doesn't know what `BOOL` means. This is not a built-in keyword in C++. Windows programs often use `BOOL` because it is defined in the `windows.h` header file. In order to use it, you must `#include` this file.

To explain a little bit further, the example code as given is not meant to be a complete program. There are several pieces missing in order to compile and run it:

1. You need to `#include <windows.h>`.
2. You need a `main()` or a `WinMain()` function which tells the computer where your program starts. Usually `WinMain()` is used for Windows programs and often contains a loop to start event handling.
3. (optionally) You need a `WinProc()` function if you want to handle events and create a UI.

This assumes using the WinAPI. If you want to use MFC instead, you need similar setup code, but I am unfamiliar with the details. Programming with the WinAPI or MFC is fairly complex. You first need to learn the ins and outs of the C and/or C++ languages before venturing into this area.

Comment: Who says you need a window procedure? What about those hello-world Windows programs that just show a message box? My point being that there's a lot more to the Windows API than event handling and UI.

Comment: @chris Good point. My experience is with event handling. I have updated my answer to indicate that WinProc() is optional. The main point remains that the example code does not stand on its own.

Comment: for Answer 1, can you give a small example of this please?
This is my way to learn things.

Comment: @user1687536 Do you know what a `#include` directive is? If not, then you have jumped into the deep end of the pool. You should start where you are by learning some basic C programming, perhaps with a Hello, World program. There are many resources online to help you get started.

Comment: in know what is #include.. this is not the part that i need an example for.. tha part that i need example is the WinMain() and WinProc(). i know prorgraming in AutoIt3 and i  wrote some software with AutoIt3 .. So it can help me .. But in C + + I'm new. and im very like to "jump into the deep end of the pool"

Comment: @user1687536 My apologies. When you said you wanted an example for Answer 1, I thought you meant the #include. As for an example of WinMain(), I suggest that you google for one. There are many resources on the Web to help you learn WinAPI programming.

Comment: @user1687536 I have also updated my answer to explain why you are getting that particular error message.

Comment: ok. I have a question, this code is supposed to be in WinProc ()?

The end result should be a command to magnify.exe ..

Comment: No, this code doesn't belong in WinProc(). Again, I suggest that you use Google to find more detailed information on Windows programming. As my answer explains, the code you have given is insufficient to create a .exe file, at the very least you must havea `main()` or `WinMain()` function to make a .exe.

Comment: Last question, is there an C++ editor as the AutoIt3 editor?
in AutoIt3 editor if I start writing a command then it offers me a list of commands after I wrote the first letter.

Photo:
http://i.imgur.com/0K23K.png

The second good thing is:
http://i.imgur.com/qDXAL.png

There is an editor that does the same thing?

Comment: @user1687536 It sounds like you are talking about an IDE. There are several of these kinds of editors for C++. Dev-C++, which you are using, is one of them. I don't know if it has this feature or not. If it does, it might need to be configured to recognize the functions, classes, and other declarations from the WinAPI and MFC. Most Windows programmers use Visual C++, which definitely has auto-completion -- this is the name of the feature you have described.

Comment: Visual C++ is a Editor that does what I described?
if so then where i can download this editor?

Comment: I've been patient with all your questions. Now it's your turn to do something for yourself. Most of your recent questions can be answered with a [Google](http://www.google.com) search. If you don't find what you need, feel free to come back and post another question with details of what you have tried and explain clearly where you are stuck.